# How to use the asp.net button to validate by jquery and then go to the behind code web form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an asp.net webform and I want to validate the textboxes first
Then after that (after success), go to the behind code cs
but now when I press the button it doesn't work

the jquery code:
...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         (function () {
             'use strict';
             window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                 var form = document.getElementById('needs-validation');
                 form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                         if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                         event.preventDefault();
                         event.stopPropagation();
                     }
                    form.classList.add('was-validated');
                }, false);
            }, false);
        })();
    </script>
```

...

the aspx page:
...

```
    <div class="form-row" style="z-index:1">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4" style="z-index:1">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Birth Date</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Birth_Date" class="form-control" runat="server" style="text-align:center" ValidationGroup="check" required></asp:TextBox>
      <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="Birth_Date" Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
      </cc1:CalendarExtender>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">  
                  enter date
             </div>
          </div></div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="inputEmail4">phone number</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Phone" class="form-control"  runat="server" style="text-align:center; z-index:-1" ValidationGroup="check" pattern="^\d{10}$" required></asp:TextBox>
         <div class="invalid-feedback">  
                  enter phone
             </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="signup" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">save</asp:LinkButton>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

...

the cs code:
...

```
protected void signup_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if(Page.IsValid)
        {
            Birth_Date.Text = "ُWelcome";
        }
        }
```

...

I have more textbox in my aspx page

Comment: You don't have `OnClick` event on your `ID="signup"` button. If you wish to do something before submitting, also add `OnClientClick` event and call whatever js function you wish. By `OnClientClick` you can also stop submission from happening

Comment: what you have is web forms, not win forms

Comment: @JayNyxed i add OnClick and OnClientClick and didn't work , but when i used button of html it work ! but i can't access behind code after success script validation

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
         function ftn(){
             'use strict';
             window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                 var form = document.getElementById('needs-validation');
                 form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                         if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                         event.preventDefault();
                         event.stopPropagation();
                     }
                    form.classList.add('was-validated');
                }, false);
            }, false);
        }
    </script>
```

and add onclientclick property to asp:button

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="signup" onclientclick="ftn()" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">save</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: It didn't work ! when i press button nothing appears !!

Comment: Add this [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "Func()", true);] to your button click event.